# What is the best way to move lots of photos between two iPads?

Tags: ios, ipad, photos, file-transfer

The business I work for currently has two iPads: One third generation and one fourth generation. They are each tied to a separate Apple ID. The third generation iPad currently has tons of photos and albums that we would like to get onto the fourth generation iPad, preferably keeping the albums intact. Many of the albums have upwards of 100 photos.

The reason we want to do this is that we would like to take one iPad to show photos to clients at different job sites, while keeping another iPad at our office for customers who come straight to our showroom. At the same time, we want to be able to keep all the other content on the iPads (apps, music, etc.) separate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [PhotoSync](http://www.photosync-app.com/) for this. $1.99 (on the US/Canada App Stores), and can transfer between any number of devices. From their site:

> Direct transfer of photos & videos between your iOS devices (iPhone,
>   iPad, iPod Touch) over Wi-Fi and Bluetooth - no computer needed! [Read more](http://www.photosync-app.com/photosync/en/features.html).

Alternatively, [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or even the built-in [Photo Stream](http://www.apple.com/ca/icloud/features/photo-stream.html) may help, but the latter doesn't give you much control and you're syncing photos through the Internet  in either case: PhotoSync transfers directly over Wi-fi.